# Decrypting Haskell type error message in simple case

Tags: haskell

What represents `[t0] -> a0 -> [a1]` in this error message? I just realized I must be applying `(:)` to `foldr`. Why is compiler not complaining that `(*2)` expects something of kind `*` as argument?

```
Prelude> foldr (:) . (* 2) [] [1..10]

<interactive>:141:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `[t0] -> a0 -> [a1]'
                with actual type `[a2]'
    In the first argument of `* 2', namely `[]'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `(* 2) [] [1 .. 10]'
    In the expression: foldr (:) . (* 2) [] [1 .. 10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation of the error message

We have

```
foldr (:) ::  [a] -> ([a] -> [a])
(.)       :: (c   -> d           ) -> (b -> c) -> (b -> d)
```

From this, we conclude that the second argument `y` in the composition

```
foldr (:) . y
```

must result in a list, i.e., be of type

```
e -> [a]
```

In our case, `y = (* 2) [] [1..10]`. So we have:

```
(* 2) [] [1..10] :: e -> [a]  -- for some e and a
```

Thus:

```
(* 2) [] :: [f] -> e -> [a]  -- for some e, a and f where (Num f, Enum f)
```

(The constraints on `f` are because we use numeric literals and range notation in the
list `[1..10]`.) Now, consider that `2` and `(*)` are overloaded, and

```
(* 2) :: Num g => g -> g
```

From this we get that `[]` must have the same type as `(* 2) []` (and that type must be an instance of `Num`):

```
[] :: [f] -> e -> [a]  -- for some e, a and f where
                       --   (Num f, Enum f, Num ([f] -> e -> [a]))
```

But this is not true, because `[]` has type `[g]` for some `g`. Now let's look at the
error message again:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[t0] -> a0 -> [a1]'
            with actual type `[a2]'
In the first argument of `* 2', namely `[]'
```

So modulo renaming of type variables, this is exactly what the error message says.

#### Addendum

The error points to `` `[]' ``, so it's perhaps enlightening to see what the typechecker thinks should go in this position. In GHC 7.8, we'll be able to use the `TypeHoles` extension for this, but for now, an easy way to do it is to abstract from `[]`, i.e., replace it by a function argument:

```
Prelude> :t \ x -> foldr (:) . (* 2) x [1..10]
\ x -> foldr (:) . (* 2) x [1..10]
  :: (Enum t, Num ([t] -> a -> [a1]), Num t) =>
     ([t] -> a -> [a1]) -> a -> [a1] -> [a1]
```

From this, you can easily see that this term is actually still type-correct, it only
requires `x` to be of the type

```
[t] -> a -> [a1]
```

with the additional class constraints (which are admittedly unlikely to hold).

Answer (score 8):

So the type of `foldr` is

```
 foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

So you're passing it `(:)` so it's type becomes

```
 foldr (:) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

However, you then try to compose it with `(*2) [] [1..10]`. This isn't even well typed so you're in trouble. I think your problem here is that function application is the highest precedence of all.

```
  foldr ((:) . (*2)) [] [1..10]
```

The explicit parens are necessary.

By the way, you can just use

```
 map (*2) [1..10]
```